# Validate user control on parent page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

How to validate user control textbox through parent page?

User controls are added dynamically on asp.net page and they need to be validated on save button which is on (parent) asp.net page.

Text boxes on user controls are being validated through client script.

Once the controls are added dynamically, validation works and shows error message but values are being saved on 'save' button. If i input '5' then i get error message and if i click the save button the value '5' is saved.

**User Control**

```
   <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstReportingHrs" runat="server" Width="102px" class="initval"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="rtxtERH" runat="server"  CssClass="required" ValidationGroup="btnSave" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txtEstReportingHrs" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateReportingHrs" Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
   </td>
```

**User Control Script**

```
function ValidateReportingHrs(sender, args) {
var RHMatchexpression = /^(([0-3])?(\.(0|25|5|75)0*)?|4(\.(0|25|5)0*)?)$/;
var re = new RegExp(RHMatchexpression);

if (args.Value == "") {
    sender.innerHTML = "* Required";
    args.IsValid = false;
    return;
}

if (args.Value > 4.5) {
    sender.innerHTML = "* excessive reporting time";
    args.IsValid = false;
    return;
}


if (!re.test(args.Value)) {
    sender.innerHTML = "* Invalid";
    args.IsValid = false;
    return;
}

args.IsValid = true;
return;
```

}

**Asp.net Page**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save Details" ID="btnSave" Width="130px" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it like this:

```
   function ValidateReportingHrs(sender, args) {
    var RHMatchexpression = /^(([0-3])?(\.(0|25|5|75)0*)?|4(\.(0|25|5)0*)?)$/;
    var re = new RegExp(RHMatchexpression);

    if (args.Value == "") {
        sender.innerHTML = "* Required";
        args.IsValid = false;

    } else if (args.Value > 4.5) {
        sender.innerHTML = "* excessive reporting time";
        args.IsValid = false;

    } else if (!re.test(args.Value)) {
        sender.innerHTML = "* Invalid";
        args.IsValid = false;

    }
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
```

}

and also validation group should be the same for button and validator.

Comment: it wouldn't get to that line if its valid.

Comment: yeh you are right .. you are returning it everytime it fails.. so thats ok .. sorry my fault @user1263981

Comment: no luck........same results. There is nothing wrong with the script , i am getting error message but values get saved on 'save' button. Client side scripting i think is working but not when save button is clicked.

Comment: one more suggestion. try updated one now. @user1263981

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72764/discussion-between-user1263981-and-irfan-tahirkheli).

Comment: button and validator should have the same ValidationGroup.  @user1263981